# What classes should convert this model data to appropriate visual representations?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So I have two different Views working with data from the same Model, but
representing it in different ways.  The Model is exposing a 2D array of values
and each View is providing a visual representation.  One View is providing a
typical image View and is using an Image class to do so.  The other is
providing an ASCII view.  The question is, should I do the conversion from the
Model's 2D array data to the different representations using ViewModels or
should this be done in the View, possibly through the use of IValueConverters or DataTemplates?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use value converters when the type being used by the view is view-specific, for example, if you are converting an enumeration of `White` and `Black` from your model into a `Brush` to be used for a background.  In this case the converter is now part of your view.

On the other hand, if you only need to reorganize the data structure or expose different properties, and all the resulting types are not view-specific, then I recommend using another view-model property or another view-model altogether.  This would still be reusable if you were to switch to a different view framework.

Answer (score 0):

That depends.  If the property value you are exposing does not have to be modified in order for your view to be able to present it, then you should use datatemplate.

If the properties need to be transformed in a more convenient form without actually mimmicking UI elements then I would suggest your Viewmodel to expose it in that format.

If you actually need to morph the properties to a UI element of some kind (color, Visibility, ...) then IValueConverters are an easy way to do this.